# JPA eclipselink cache and DB replication

Tags: sql-server, caching, jpa, eclipselink, database-replication

we currently have a java based application which uses JPA via eclipselink against a single MS sql server, this is running on a system in the internal network.
This works fine.

Now we need to add a second instance of the sql database in a DMZ with it's own application and JPA eclipselink. (External access to a subset of the application)

Both applications should see the same data, which means I will have to do some replication between the two.
MS SQL has a merge replication system for this which would cover our needs.
But here I struggle with the JPA cache.

When the data is changed directly by the db replication, how/when do I invalidate the local jpa cache?

Or is there a java/jpa/jdbc based replication available for such setups?

Any other ideas on how to handle such a situation?

Comment: which jpa cache? l1 (entity manager), or l2 (EMF)?

Comment: EMF for sure, but I1 would be nice too, otherwise we will have lost updates...

Answer (score 1):

EMF L2 cache is cleared using

```
emf.getCache().evictAll()
```

Comment: Yes, I know this, but how do I know when to call it, when the database is doing the replication below the java VM level?

Comment: that is beyond the scope of JPA clearly, and only you know when the replication is being done (or call something via JDBC or JPA native query on your database to find out)